# Manual Pagination for PowerShell command for SharePoint 2010/13 other than Out-host -paging

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

I want manual pagination for PowerShell commands for SharePoint such as `Get-SPUser` or `Get-SPSite`. I know there is command viz. **Out-Host -paging** facility available but it is not manual pagination i.e. it does not take argument of `pageSize=30`. I want a facility of taking this argument of `pageSize` so that it will display those many records ( in this case say 30 ) per page.

-Limit parameter does not take range like (0..10) or (10..20) so it is also not useful

Can anybody help how to accomplish manual pagination for PowerShell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is manual pagination available by select-object command as follows

```
Get-SPUser -web <siteCollectionURL> | select-object -Index (0..10)
```

This command will produce first 10 users in site collection

(0..10) refers to range i.e. from index 0 to 10

Thus one can achieve manual pagination by playing with indices using -Index parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box you can use `more` or `out-host`. In both cases we won't be able to set number of items to be displayed.

In your case you can try storing the items in an Array object and then iterate it based on your page length.